# Symfony2 WebApp Deployment

Tags: php, linux, apache, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to deploy a symfony2 webapp on a VPS server. That server has a different PHP version installed on web (5.4) and command line client (5.2). In order to install vendors with composer, I cannot use PHP-CLI because of its version (it needs PHAR support, included on PHP 5.3). Is there any way I can use php motor that uses Apache (5.4) on CLI?

I realize that PHP5.4 is installed on `/opt/php54` but no `bin` folder is inside.

Thanks guys!

EDIT

By the way, `which php` command returns `/usr/bin/php` which is the PHP52 binary.

Comment: Can't you update php manually? Do you striclty need PHP 5.2 for some reason?

Comment: I cannot update php mannualy due to hosting restrictions. I don't need (even want) PHP 5.2

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find the PHP54 binary and execute the composer installation.

The binary path depends on the linux distribution.

These commands might help to find it:

```
which php
whereis php
```

Please take a look at the `/usr` folder and `/usr/local/bin/php`.

Or: just place a little script in the web folder with `<?php echo PHP_BINDIR; echo PHP_BINARY;` - it will show the path to php.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
These two commands returns the binary path on /usr/bin/php, that is the PHP52 binary.
Otherwise, you say that phpinfo() will show the path of binary, can you tell me where? Thx!

Comment: And there isn't a `/usr/bin/php54`? Hmm, i think it should be part of the $_SERVER settings, $_SERVER['_']. Maybe i mixed things up. If it's not part of phpinfo, you can still use these two constants `PHP_BINDIR` and `PHP_BINARY` to find the binary

Comment: @JensA.Koch: If a different version of PHP isn't installed then he can't locate it.

Comment: @DonCallisto True, but that assumption is not what he described in his question. He stated that the server has PHP54 for web and PHP52 for cli. So from my perspective, it's just a matter of finding the binary for PHP54 and using that on the cli for composer.

Comment: @JensA.Koch: Didn't noticed. Sorry.